# How to pin HubTile control to start screen in Windows phone Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am using the Hubtile Control provided in the Silverlight toolkit ( August) and I haven't been able to figure out how to pin the tiles to the homepage. Totally clueless and I have thoroughly searched everywhere with no luck. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the [ShellTile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltile%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) API as described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202979%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to add a secondary tile to the Start screen.

If you're using HubTile controls within your application, then you'll need to handle a touch gesture (e.g. Tap event) to determine which tile to pin, but it all depends on your app.

Comment: And what one can do, is to render the HubTile control into a Image, and use that image as a background for the ShellTile. I think [my guide](http://windcape.posterous.com/how-to-generate-a-custom-live-tile-directly-o) might come in handy for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the article that gives you answer in more details, including the code:

http://igrali.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/how-to-pin-a-hubtile-to-start-screen/

Basically, you create a new StandardTileData and then call ShellTile.Create. The information for the StandardTileData object should be passed from the HubTile object:

```
        private void CreateLiveTile(HubTile hubtile)
        {

        StandardTileData LiveTile = new StandardTileData
        {
            BackgroundImage = ((System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage)
                               hubtile.Source).UriSource,
            Title = hubtile.Title,
            BackTitle = hubtile.Title,
            BackContent = hubtile.Message
        };
```

Find more details in the article!

Regards